# Continuously polling a NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc

I am wondering if it is possible to poll whether a (passive) NFC Tag is still present on an unmodified Android device. For instance, I put my phone on a NFC tag and I want to poll every, say minute or so, whether the tag is still attached to the backside of my phone. So, I would like to do a periodical request, or periodically read the data from the NFC chip.

So far, I have not found anything about this. Therefore, I am wondering if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check the presence of a tag:
[isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#isConnected())